# How to check which package/process updated nsswitch?

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, nsswitch.conf

I've experincing problems with my `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. I'm not longer able to use `sudo` as my personal user (ldap).

I've checked dpkg.log, and it seems it's been som upgrades on the packages which matches the date of the /etc/nsswitch.conf modification.

How can I further verify which package has edited the /etc/nsswitch.conf?
I didn't get any useful results when I ran `grep -rHi nsswitch /var/log`.

I suspect sudo-ldap, but I'm not sure.

**EDIT:** I've found this: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+question/706189. However, I'd like to know if it's possible to figure this out on the system itself!

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use `audit` daemon. Just create record like this:

```
auditctl -w /etc/nsswitch.conf -p w -k monitor-nsswitch
```

this will create logs on every write in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought, like Romeo was to try to capture who/what is changing the files - but really it would be *very* surprising if that was anything other than root/apt or dpkg. It *seems* that your issue is not how these files were changed, but how to recover/prevent future occurrences. If you are looking at log files, then I'm guessing that you have root access and and just need to re-apply the desired config to recover. That just leaves the issue of preventing future occurrences.

As you probably already know, apt is a front-end to dpkg.

`man dpkg`

is a good place to start. Amongst the other options you'll find the `--force-things` options. `--force-conffold` will preserve your configuration. To apply this in an interactive update:

```
apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" update
```

And you can also set this for invocation of apt in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ (using "Dpkg::Options {...}").

I don't think its possible to set these options for specific packages - but I could be wrong.

An alternative approach would be to set the immutable flag on the configs you wat to preserve - but this will need tested / may cause the update to fail.